# stargazer: error 'names' attribute must be the same length as vector

Tags: r, stargazer

I want to use stargazer to export a table as .html:

```
iso <- c("AUT", "AUT", "BEG", "BEG", "BEG")
year <- c(2005, 2006, 2003, 2006, 2007)
tab1 <- table(iso, year)
stargazer(tab1, type = "html", summary = FALSE, out = "table1.html")
```

this gives me the following error:

> Error in names(x) <- value : 'names' attribute [4] must be the same
> length as the vector [3]

I don't understand what this means, is it because I have 4 distinct years? How can I get the code to work?

Answer (score 0):

`stargazer` does not accept `table` objects:

> one or more model objects (for regression analysis tables) or data
> frames/vectors/matrices (for summary statistics, or direct output of
> content). They can also be included as lists (or even lists within
> lists).

What you can do is use `as.data.frame` for you input:

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(as.data.frame(tab1), type = "html", summary = FALSE, out = "table1.html")
```

Output:

```
<table style="text-align:center"><tr><td colspan="4" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>iso</td><td>year</td><td>Freq</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="4" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">1</td><td>AUT</td><td>2003</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">2</td><td>BEG</td><td>2003</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">3</td><td>AUT</td><td>2005</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">4</td><td>BEG</td><td>2005</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">5</td><td>AUT</td><td>2006</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">6</td><td>BEG</td><td>2006</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">7</td><td>AUT</td><td>2007</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:left">8</td><td>BEG</td><td>2007</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="4" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr></table>
```